# Problem opening GRASS GUI: libgeos-3.3.6.so: cannot open shared object file:

Tags: grass-gis, gui

I have been using GRASS to process some Landsat imagery but very recently, and as far as I am aware - after having done nothing different or changing the settings, I am trying to use GRASS and on start-up I receive the message:

```
GRASS 6.4.2 (newLocation):~ > 3D view mode: libgeos-3.3.6.so: cannot open shared  object file: No such file or directory
3D view mode: libgeos-3.3.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
3D view mode: libgeos-3.3.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
g.list: error while loading shared libraries: libgeos-3.3.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
g.list: error while loading shared libraries: libgeos-3.3.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
GRASS module 'g.region' not found. Unable to start map display window.
```

Consequently the GRASS GUI does not open once I have chosen my location (I have tested a range of locations that previously opened fine).  I am using NX client to run GRASS.

Would anyone be able to help with this error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the (lib)geos package. Which operating system are you using?